# store JSON string in csv file for neo4j import

Tags: python, json, neo4j

I need to store a `JSON` string in one of the fields of a `csv` file that is going to be used to create a `neo4j` database with `neo4j-admin import`. After I generate all of the necessary `csv` files and try to create the database it is writing me that there are no valid `--nodes` files. I suspect this is an issue of quoting specifically in the `csv`'s with `JSON` strings stored. Here is the code I am using for the generation of `csv` files:

```
with open(cl_file,'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(title_list)
        for row in unique_cl_data:
            writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], 'Cluster', dataset_name])
```

The `JSON` string is stored in the `row[3]` value and looks like that:

```
'{"mature_neuron":0.493694929,"intermediate_progenitor_cell":0.0982259823,"immature_neuron":0.1773570713,"glutamatergic_neuron":0.6074802751,"gabaergic_neuron":0.2685863644,"dopaminergic_neuron":0.0234599396,"serotonergic_neruon":0.001022236,"cholinergic_neuron":0.0273108961,"neuroepithelial_cell":0.2173953827,"radial_glia":0.2758471756,"microglia":0.0282818013,"macrophage":0.0,"astrocyte":0.3250249223,"oligodendrocyte_precursor_cell":0.4788073089,"mature_oligodendrocyte":0.3684283806,"schwann_cell_precursor":0.2158159088,"myelinating_schwann_cell":0.3282158992,"nonmyelinating_schwann_cell":0.4526564331,"endothelial_cell":0.7830818309,"mural_cell":0.0756233339}'
```

The generated `csv` looks like that:

```
"clusterId:ID","chartType","clusterName","assign",":LABEL","DATASET"
"scid_engram_fear_traned_tsne_1","tsne","1","{""mature_neuron"":0.793159869,""intermediate_progenitor_cell"":0.000454013,""immature_neuron"":0.0548508584,""glutamatergic_neuron"":1.0792403847,""gabaergic_neuron"":0.3181778459,""dopaminergic_neuron"":0.150589103,""serotonergic_neruon"":0.0096765336,""cholinergic_neuron"":0.0251700647,""neuroepithelial_cell"":0.0594110346,""radial_glia"":0.1539441058,""microglia"":0.0224593362,""macrophage"":0.0300658893,""astrocyte"":0.0996221719,""oligodendrocyte_precursor_cell"":0.0051255739,""mature_oligodendrocyte"":0.0223153229,""schwann_cell_precursor"":0.029507684,""myelinating_schwann_cell"":0.0360644031,""nonmyelinating_schwann_cell"":0.4626932582,""endothelial_cell"":0.0006433937,""mural_cell"":0.0}","Cluster","scid_engram_fear_traned"
```

As can be seen there are double quotation marks around the keys of the `JSON` strings. I suspect that is the issue, but am not sure. I do not know how to avoid such quotation from happening if it is the cause of the failed import. `csv.QUOTE_ALL` has always been working for me (before I tried to store a `JSON` string).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I just substituted some characters in `row[3]` which worked out fine (same `QUOTE_ALL`) using:

```
row[3].replace('"', '\\"').replace('\n', '\\n')
```

When reading in the fields on the front end I needed to substitute the characters back:

```
JSON.parse(jsonStr.replace(/\\"/g, '"'))
```